# pydub.playback.play() not playing sound

Tags: python, audio, wav, pydub

I am trying to play a .wav file in Python like so:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav('test.wav')
play(sound)
```

But the sound is not playing. When I type just `sound` I get a box with the option to play, as expected (see picture below). When I play the sound from this box, it sounds like it should. But I want to play the sound automatically using the `play` function.

[image]

Does anyone know why `play` is not working here, or know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In order to play audio with `pydub` you need to install one of these:

[image]

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#playback